# Android caffe ForwardPrefilled() doesn't work in Multithread objects

Tags: android, android-ndk, caffe

I'm getting problems with  m_caffe_net->forwardPrefilled but only with android threading case.

My algorithm is a basic caffe process such as:

load models-> process-> get the result. (CPU mode)

If I integrate the code in the ui thread everything works fine. But Android says that 
this is not a good tip because of freezing gui.

I tested threads, AsyncTask and runnables, and always get the same SIGSEV 11 error

So I tested my call-stack in Android Studio and I noticed that the last call was omp_get_num_threads.

[image]

Is it necesary to use openmp set_num_threads omp function to exec forwardPrefilled() in multicore mode?

My sample is similar to this:

https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-demo

Caffe lib compilation is this:

https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-lib

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

I disabled openmp option in caffe script/build_caffe.sh file.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="${WD}/android-cmake/android.toolchain.cmake" \
      -DANDROID_NDK="${NDK_ROOT}" \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DANDROID_ABI="${ANDROID_ABI}" \
      -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=21 \
      -DANDROID_USE_OPENMP=OFF \
      -DADDITIONAL_FIND_PATH="${ANDROID_LIB_ROOT}" \
      -DBUILD_python=OFF \
      -DBUILD_docs=OFF \
      -DCPU_ONLY=ON \
      -DUSE_LMDB=ON \
      -DUSE_LEVELDB=OFF \
      -DUSE_HDF5=OFF \
      -DBLAS=${BLAS} \
      -DBOOST_ROOT="${BOOST_HOME}" \
      -DGFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR="${GFLAGS_HOME}/include" \
      -DGFLAGS_LIBRARY="${GFLAGS_HOME}/lib/libgflags.a" \
      -DGLOG_INCLUDE_DIR="${GLOG_ROOT}/include" \
      -DGLOG_LIBRARY="${GLOG_ROOT}/lib/libglog.a" \
      -DOpenCV_DIR="${OPENCV_ROOT}" \
      -DPROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE="${ANDROID_LIB_ROOT}/protobuf_host/bin/protoc" \
      -DPROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR="${PROTOBUF_ROOT}/include" \
      -DPROTOBUF_LIBRARY="${PROTOBUF_ROOT}/lib/libprotobuf.a" \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${ANDROID_LIB_ROOT}/caffe" \
```

The result is a little bit slower but it works :).